# Netbeans dark theme still white

Tags: java, netbeans

I changed my netbeans ide to darktheme but for some reason the actual text itself is still white. Has anyone had this issue before?

[image: My IDE]

Comment: Ok, not sure what you did, but.  Under "Options"/"Preferences".  Make sure that "Fonts & Colors" is using the correct preset "Profile" (I'm using "FlatLaf Dark") and under "Appearance/Look And Feel", make sure it's using "FlatLaf Dark" to.  This seems to work for me (sweet).  You can play around with the "Fonts & Colors" independently of main applications look and feel, because, why not ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you so much it worked! I don't know why it but it was auto set to the default light theme even when I switched to the "FlatLaf" under appearance -> look and feel lol

Comment: I didn't know they had dark mode :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, I'm using Netbeans 12.3 (just updated)

[image: Netbeans 12]

I had to set both the "Fonts & Colors" and "Appearance" settings.  Start by going to "Tools/Options" (I'm not on Windows, but I think that's right) or "Apache Netbeans/Preferences" if you're on Mac.

Go to the "Fonts & Colors", set the "Profile" to "FlatLaf Dark" (or, anything you like :D)

[image: Fonts and Colors]

Go to "Appearance/Look and Feel" and set the "Preferred look and feel" to "FlatLaf Dark" (or, anything your like :D)

[image: Apperence]

Hello dark mode!

Comment: One minor additional detail is that a restart of NetBeans is necessary before the change to _Look and Feel_ becomes effective, whereas the effect of the _Fonts & Colors_ change is immediate. At least that's how it worked out for me just now on NetBeans 12.3 on Windows.

Comment: Didn't it prompt you?  I think it promoted me, but good comment though

Comment: Yes, there was an advisory message for me. I was wondering if that also occurred on Mac as well more than anything - that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and i think it is because of your NetBeans version.
You need to update your NetBeans version to 12.3